# What is wrong with my SuluSyliusConsumerBundle configuration?

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq, sylius, sulu, symfony-messenger

I have a Sulu and a Sylius application which I am trying to integrate using the SuluSyliusBundle and RabbitMQ. I have added the following configs...

messenger.yaml

```
framework:
router:
    resource: "%kernel.project_dir%/config/routing_%sulu.context%.yml"
messenger:
    # Uncomment this (and the failed transport below) to send failed messages to this transport for later handling.
    # failure_transport: failed
    buses:
        message_bus:
            middleware:
                - doctrine_transaction
                - event_middleware
    # Uncomment this (and the failed transport below) to send failed messages to this transport for later handling.
    # failure_transport: failed

    transports:
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transport-configuration
        # async: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
        # failed: 'doctrine://default?queue_name=failed'
        # sync: 'sync://'

    routing:
        # Route your messages to the transports
        # 'App\Message\YourMessage': async
```

sulu_sylius_consumer.yaml

```
  sylius_base_url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8001'
  sylius_default_channel: 'default_channel'
  sylius_oauth_config:
    username: api
    password: api
    client_id: demo_client
    client_secret: secret_demo_client
  route_defaults_fallback:
    view: 'templates/products/default'
  firewall_provider_key: 'main'
```

The issue is that once I install the bundle and add these two configs, I get the following error
[image]

I believe this is being caused by the config in the messenger. I have added the routes to routes_admin.yaml as it is show in the documentation [here](https://github.com/sulu/SuluSyliusConsumerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/installation.md):

routes_admin.yaml

```
app_events:
    type: rest
    resource: App\Controller\Admin\EventController
    prefix: /admin/api
    name_prefix: app.
    options:
        expose: true

app_event_registrations:
    type: rest
    resource: App\Controller\Admin\EventRegistrationController
    prefix: /admin/api
    name_prefix: app.
    options:
        expose: true

app_locations:
    type: rest
    resource: App\Controller\Admin\LocationController
    prefix: /admin/api
    name_prefix: app.
    options:
        expose: true

app_products:
    type: rest
    resource: App\Controller\Admin\ProductsController
    prefix: /admin/api
    name_prefix: app.
    options:
        expose: true

sulu_route:
    mappings:
        Sulu\Bundle\SyliusConsumerBundle\Model\RoutableResource\RoutableResource:
            generator: schema
            resource_key: product_content
            options:
                route_schema: "/products/{object.getCode()}"
```

routes_website.yaml

```
app.event:
    path: /{_locale}/event/{id}
    controller: App\Controller\Website\EventWebsiteController::indexAction

app.product:
    path: /{_locale}/product/{id}
    controller: App\Controller\Website\ProductWebsiteController::indexAction
```

What can I do to fix this error?
[edit: added routes_admin and routes_website yaml]

Comment: I have tried to install the bundle in a clean sulu installation and i cannot reproduce the error. can you post the content of your routing_admin.yml? have you added something there?

Comment: The only things I have added are the exercises from the Sulu Workshop, as well as my own product entity + its admin controller. It it perhaps because I am continuing from the workshop? I will try this from a fresh Sulu installation as well.

Comment: it seems that it was just an error in config for messenger. Thanks